# Large File (more than ~2 Mb) Upload - raises error "Key 'data_file' not found in <MultiValueDict: {}>" : Google App Engine/Python

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-app-engine, file-upload

Quick notes - I'm trying to upload random size files to save at datastore using GAE.

Here is basic code:

- **HTML Code**

  ```
  <iframe name="upload_iframe" src="" style="display:none;"></iframe>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
    <input name="data_file" size="30000" type="file" /> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
  ```
- **Python / Django Code**

  ```
   def upload_files(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
         logging.info(request.FILES)
         logging.info(request.FILES['data_file'])

      return HttpResponse('File Uploaded Successfully..')
  ```

**Test scenario** :

- If i try to upload ~1 Mb file, its working fine.. returns `File Uploaded Successfully`
- if trying to upload ~2 Mb or more then it raises `MultiValueDictKeyError: "Key 'data_file' not found in <MultiValueDict: {}>"` :- not able to picked up where am i doing wrong here or using wrong approch..

I referred this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010747/empty-request-files-with-django-upload-forms/5567063#5567063) too..but its not working for me.

Please suggest you thought on above..

Comment: Some tips: Use `{% csrf_protect %}`; get rid of the hidden `MAX_FILE_SIZE` because it is not doing anything useful; and there is no `size` attribute for file input tag.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Thanks for your reply.. Could you please elaborate this tips with some example or with use of `{% csrf_protect %}` ?

Comment: See the [documentation on CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/)

Answer (score 0):

Django loads small file uploads into memory, while saving large uploads temporary to disk. GAE doesn't allow access to the file-system, so you have to incorporate GAE's blobstore as storage engine. Also refer to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014147/django-on-google-app-engine-cannot-upload-images).